# Get AD Group Members - exclude computers

Tags: powershell, active-directory, get-aduser

I have security groups with users and computers. I want to list ONLY the users within the security groups. I am getting the list of users but also getting an error for each computer in the security group:

```
Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'CN="*
```

The script I am using is below:

```
$GroupName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the Group Name'
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName -Recursive | 
Get-ADUser  -Properties Name,Mail,Title,Department | Sort-Object Department,Title,Name | Format-Table Name,Mail,Title,Department -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Get-ADGroupMember` use `Get-ADUser` with a filter to find, *recursively*, all members of the group:

```bash
$GroupName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the Group Name'
$groupDn = (Get-ADGroup -Identity $GroupName).DistinguishedName
$getADUserSplat = @{
    LDAPFilter = "(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=$groupDn)"
    Properties = 'Name', 'Mail', 'Title', 'Department'
}

Get-ADUser @getADUserSplat |
    Sort-Object Department, Title, Name |
    Format-Table Name, Mail, Title, Department -AutoSize
```

See also [**Active Directory: LDAP Syntax Filters**](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) for details on **LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN** (`1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941`).

Comment: Thanks, working great for me, but I will need to understand the LDAP filter portion. Merry Christmas.